# XMLHttpRequest - How to trap situation where an HTML error page is returned instead of data

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

Javascript: Using XMLHttpRequest to get a small amount of data which is echo'd to it by a specific php routine on a webserver. Async with callback function. Or synchronous, makes no odds.

The issue arises if the php file is absent or inaccessible. Instead of returning an error flag, the responseText property returns the HTML content of a server 404 error page.

The 404 page content will vary from server to server so it's virtually impossible to trap this situation by any string test. Is there any way to flag the fact that an error has happened and return null instead?

```
 // envvars is set previously
 AjaxRequest.open('post','handler.php?nocache='+nocache,true);
 AjaxRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",'Firefox');
 AjaxRequest.onreadystatechange = aCallback;
 AjaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 AjaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", envvars.length);
 AjaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 AjaxRequest.send(envvars);
}

function aCallback() {
 if(AjaxRequest.readyState == 4){
   var response = AjaxRequest.responseText;
   if(response == 0){
     // It is useless to test for failure here because a complete 404 page is returned, 
     // instead of a null or -1 response. 
     document.ajax.response.value="Fail";   
    } else {
     document.ajax.response.value=response;   
   }
 }
}

// handler.php:
if ($_POST["request"]=="countbananas"):
  echo "bananas=43" ;
endif;
```

ps I know jQuery will be mentioned but I'd rather avoid that route.

Comment: Can't you detect if the HTTP status code is 404?

Comment: Think I've found the answer. The AjaxRequest.status property will be 200 if OK. Looks like the guy who wrote the sample I based my code on used didn't know how to trap the error properly. Took a while to discover that this property exists, very few examples mention it.  Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [`status` property of the `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#status) object to get the HTTP response code:

```
function aCallback() {
 if(AjaxRequest.readyState == 4){
   if(AjaxRequest.status !== 200){
     // something went wrong
     document.ajax.response.value="Fail";   
    } else {
     var response = AjaxRequest.responseText;
     document.ajax.response.value=response;   
   }
 }
}
```

This of course assumes, that your source is returning proper HTTP code, such as "404 File not found".

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) returned by the XMLHttpRequest?

```
if ( AjaxRequest.status + "" == "404" ) {
  // Error page
}
```

Or:

```
// 4xx status code
if ( (AjaxRequest.status + "").substr(0,1) == "4" ) {
  // Error page
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, we've figured out that the sample I used had an incorrect error handling method. That is the right way.